# File upload with form inputs AJAX not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I've been searching for solutions across SO and have tried them, but not one of the answers I found has solved my problem. So here is it.

I am working on a simple web app with input details and file upload (.docx files). I used `FormData` for the handling of form data, but the server-side operation only works for the form inputs like `text, password, date` ,etc.

This is my JS code; the commented lines are the one which I attempted but did not work.

```
var myForm = $("#add-thesis-form");
    var formData = new FormData(myForm);

    //var formData = myForm.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: "thesis-scripts/add_thesis.php",
        data: formData
        // processData: false,
        // contentType: false
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#addThesisModal').modal('hide');
        alert(data);
        //alert("Successfully saved a record to the database. ");
        showThesis();
    });
```

My PHP code (using Meekro DB)

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
$categoryId = $_POST["category_id"];
$collegeId = $_POST["college_id"];
$departmentId = $_POST["department_id"];
$uploadedBy = $_SESSION["user"];
$uploadedAt = DB::queryFirstField("SELECT NOW();");
$year = $_POST["thesis_year"];
$keywords = $_POST["keywords"];
$authors = $_POST["authors"];

//FILE UPLOAD

$targ_dir = "../uploads/";
$targ_file = $targ_dir . basename($_FILES["thesis"]["name"]);
$flagOk = 1;
$tempFolder = $_FILES["thesis"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($tempFolder, $targ_file);

//!FILE UPLOAD

$result = DB::insert('theses', array(
    "title" => $title,
    "description" => $description,
    "categoryId" => $categoryId,
    "collegeId" => $collegeId,
    "departmentId" => $departmentId,
    "uploadedBy" => $uploadedBy,
    "uploadedAt" => $uploadedAt,
    "pubyear" => $year,
    "filepath" => $targ_file,
    "views" => 0,
    "rating" => 0,
    "keywords" => $keywords,
    "authors" => $authors
));
```

I've tried a `print_r($_FILES)` and that one works, but this one doesn't. Please help me. Thanks.
Setting the `contentType:false` causes the server to throw an error `Undefined index` on all the `$_POST` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your form should includes `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Maybe this would work :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST" ,
        url: "thesis-scripts/add_thesis.php",
        data: "multipart/form-data"
     ...
```